# Saving dotchart with shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Do you see any mistake here?
the `ggsave` works, but `png(file=file)` part not - it saves empty white image.

```
output$savePlotAmount <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "amount.png",
    content = function(file) {
      if(input$plotType == "dot"){
        png(file = file)
        plotAmount()
        dev.off()
      }else{
        ggsave(plotAmount(), filename = file)  
      }

    })
```

I spent "hours" on trying to repair it but I don't know what's going on. Sorry that the example is not reproductible, but it is to hard to reproduct all app.

EDIT:
What is `plotAmount()`:

```
plotAmount <- reactive({
    if(input$plotType == "violin") {
      plotAmount <- ggplot(values$x, aes_string(x = input$groupedBy, y = input$yVariableContinous)) + 
        geom_violin() +
        ggtitle(paste0(input$yVariableContinous, " grouped by ", input$groupedBy)) + 
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, quantile(values$x[,input$yVariableContinous] , 0.95, na.rm = T)))
    }
    if(input$plotType == "boxplot") {
      plotAmount <- ggplot(values$x, aes_string(x = input$groupedBy, y = input$yVariableContinous)) + 
        geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
        ggtitle(paste0(input$yVariableContinous, " grouped by ", input$groupedBy)) + 
        scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, quantile(values$x[,input$yVariableContinous] , 0.95, na.rm = T)))
    }
    if(input$plotType == "dot") {
      var <- ifelse(input$groupedBy == 1, input$xVariable, input$groupedBy) 
      agregat <- aggregate(x = values$x[,input$yVariableContinous], by = list(g = values$x[,var], xx = values$x[,input$xVariable]), FUN = input$valueAs)
      dotchart(agregat$x, labels = agregat$xx, 
               groups = as.factor(agregat$g), 
               color = brewer.pal(9,"Set1")[as.numeric(as.factor(agregat$g))],
               xlab = "salary",
               cex = .75,
               main = paste0(input$yVariableContinous, " for ", input$xVariable,
                             "\ngrouped by ", input$groupedBy),
               xlim = c(min(values$x[,input$yVariableContinous], na.rm = T), quantile(values$x[,input$yVariableContinous] , 0.95, na.rm = T)),
               pch = 16
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot2` plots need to be `print()`'d to render.

Comment: here the first part in `png(file=file)` is not ggplot. It is a dotchart - the same as basic `plot()`. And the second in `ggsave(...` works well.

Comment: `plotAmount()` is a ggplot object, right? Try a `print(plotAmount())`. See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/2.2.1/topics/print.ggplot

Comment: no, if `input$plotType == "dot"` then it is `dotchart()` which is the same as `plot()` if not then it is ggplot. I added the code of `plotAmount()`

Comment: Thanks for adding that snippet and clearing up the confusion. I don't see any issues with the dotchart plotting/saving. Is there any more to `plotAmount` that got cut off? What I do see is that the ggplots should be saving as white images since `plotAmount` isn't returning them.